# Must I install a plugin for Nginx object caching?

Tags: nginx, cache

After Enabling Nginx object caching, something I tried to do [without success, so far,](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1024606/failed-to-implement-nginx-object-caching-connection-refused) must I install some WordPress plugin to communicate with the Nginx caching system somehow or to inform Nginx what to cache exactly (for what webpages to create static webpages)?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not know plugin to control FastCGI cache in nginx. However, there are a set of nginx rules to use the WP Super Cache cache directly.

Let us think – what is going on when site page is accessed?

1. nginx accepts request and sees that index.php is needed
2. nginx starts php-fpm (what is not fast at all)
3. WordPress starts to work
4. At the beginning, WP Super Cache plugin encounters and slips already saved .html instead of infinitely long (in these timing terms) page generation

None of that is bad, but: we need to start php-fpm, and then to execute some php code, to respond with saved .html.

There is a solution how to proceed without php at all. Let us do rewrite on nginx at once.

Edit `/etc/nginx/conf.d/servers.conf` – and after `index index.php;` line insert:

```
include snippets/wp-supercache.conf;
```

Create folder `/etc/nginx/snippets` and file `wp-supercache.conf` in it with the following content:

```
rewrite ^([^.]*[^/])$ $1/ permanent;

set $cache_uri $request_uri;

# POST requests and urls with a query string should always go to PHP
if ($request_method = POST) {
    set $cache_uri 'null cache';
}
if ($query_string != "") {
    set $cache_uri 'null cache';
}

# Don't cache uris containing the following segments
if ($request_uri ~* "(/wp-admin/|/xmlrpc.php|/wp-(app|cron|login|register|mail).php
                      |wp-.*.php|/feed/|index.php|wp-comments-popup.php
                      |wp-links-opml.php|wp-locations.php |sitemap(_index)?.xml
                      |[a-z0-9_-]+-sitemap([0-9]+)?.xml)") {

    set $cache_uri 'null cache';
}

# Don't use the cache for logged-in users or recent commenters
if ($http_cookie ~* "comment_author|wordpress_[a-f0-9]+
                     |wp-postpass|wordpress_logged_in") {
    set $cache_uri 'null cache';
}

# Set the cache file
set $cachefile "/wp-content/cache/supercache/$http_host/$cache_uri/index.html";
set $gzipcachefile "/wp-content/cache/supercache/$http_host/$cache_uri/index.html.gz";
if ($https ~* "on") {
    set $cachefile "/wp-content/cache/supercache/$http_host/$cache_uri/index-https.html";
    set $gzipcachefile "/wp-content/cache/supercache/$http_host/$cache_uri/index.html.gz";
}

# Add cache file debug info as header
#add_header X-Cache-File $cachefile;

# Try in the following order: (1) gzipped cachefile, (2) cachefile, (3) normal url, (4) php
location / {
    try_files $gzipcachefile $cachefile $uri $uri/ /index.php;
}
```

Executing this instructions, nginx looks by itself, if there is .html available (or compressed .html.gz) in WP Super Cache plugin folders, and if .html exists, takes it without starting any php-fpm at all.

For more details, please read my article https://kagg.eu/en/10000-clients-second-wordpress/. Section "rewrite in nginx" describes nginx settings aimed to work together with WP Super Cache plugin.

It is a bit different than FastCGI cache in your question but works well.

Comment: Hi, thanks. What is "micro caching" of a web site?

Comment: It is the same what you do with `fastcgi_cache_path` etc.

Comment: But how it differs from caching to create static webpages with "non-micro" caching? Adding a note to the answer will be good IMO.

Comment: Your question relates to "plugin for caching", as you need to control cache created by nginx. I do not know plugin to control microcache, but I know plugin which creates own cache, and I offered a set nginx rules, which allow nginx to use this cache directly. So, my answer is not exactly what you did expect, but is solves the problem of communication between nginx and WordPress in terms of caching.

Comment: So I take there is not a  special definition for "micro caching" it's just caching - but done directly by Nginx. That's what I wanted to make sure.

Comment: I think you should say if my assumption here is correct or not.

Comment: I saw such a term in different articles, when people name "micro cahiching" everything what relates to  `fastcgi_cache_path`. The proper name in documentation http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_fastcgi_module.html is FastCGI cache. In my article mentioned in the answer, I consider using of FastCGI cache, and set itls validity for 30 seconds. Even in this case it has very bad effect, when you cannot see any update on admin page for 30 seconds. So, in practice, I switch off FastCGI cache at all.

Comment: I think it's good to edit to remove "micro-caching" term altogether. 30 Seconds?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/76089/discussion-between-kagg-design-and-user9303970).

Comment: link only answers are not an answer at all. Please add the relevant parts into the answer (there is no problem with linking to your site, but people should be able to have a useful answer even if you decide to close your site)

Comment: @MarkKaplun OK, I will do it.

Comment: @MarkKaplun done.

Comment: generally I assume you need the plugin just to generate the relevant headers, and the additional actual caching by it is a wasted effort. IMO it shpuld be enough to set the headers when there are no cookies and no url parameters (and exclude wp-admin and wp-json just to be safe)

Comment: @MarkKaplun WP Super Cache is much more complicated in its behaviour. It drops relevant cache when content is updated, it can preload caches for the whole site etc. To write a plugin with a similar functionality is a challenge.

Comment: sure, but invalidation remains a problem in any case even if it deletes the local file, as it set the headers and every caching proxy like cloudflare (or in this case the nginx server) will still retain and serve the cached page. Preloading has its own problems especially on big sites, but that is really off-topic for this question

Comment: @MarkKaplun in my config, if cached. html exists, no php code runs at all, so nobody can set a header.

Comment: ok, we are passing the SE comment limits so might as well stop here. I never played with nginx caching so not sure about all its details

Comment: Sure, just one note. This approach really works, on a number of my servers.